# Bash replace // doesn't handle anchors like Regex? Because it is glob-like

Tags: bash

So the aim is to replace a partial pathname base using a supplied regexp.
And I'd like to use the built-in regexp replacer ${path//src/dest}

```
/tmp/some\/where/ is somewhat crude, as my_tmp would be matched to stupidity
/\/tmp\//\/somewhere\// is better
/^\/tmp\//\/somewhere\// is the best, but this last one doesn't seem to work.
```

An easier example, because those backslash escapes are killers:

```
$ t2="there hello"
$ t1="hello there"
$ echo ${t1//hello/goodbye}
    goodbye there
$ echo ${t2//hello/goodbye}
    there goodbye
```

But lets say I only want the starting hello:

```
$ echo ${t2//^hello/goodbye}
    there hello            -- as required

$ echo ${t1//^hello/goodbye}
    hello there            -- but not what I want here

-- ok let's try oldschool
$ echo ${t2//~hello/goodbye}
    there hello            -- as required

$ echo ${t1//~hello/goodbye}
    hello there            -- but not what I want here

$ t3="^hello there"

$ echo ${t3//^hello/goodbye}
    goodbye there       -- ^ is just a character :-(
```

But what about =~, I hear you ask...

```
$ if [[ $t1 =~ ^hello ]] ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi
    yes

$ if [[ $t2 =~ ^hello ]] ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi
    no

$ if [[ $t3 =~ ^hello ]] ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi
    no
```

So, basically a difference in behaviour between =~ and ${//

I guess I could use =~ and $BASH_REMATCH somehow?

Using sed I get the expected answer, but I don't really want to invoke an external):

```
$ echo $t1 | sed s/^hello/goodbye/
    goodbye there
$ echo $t2 | sed s/^hello/goodbye/
    there hello
$ echo $t3 | sed s/^hello/goodbye/
    ^hello there
```

GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Are you actually trying to replace a regex, or just a fixed string (e.g. hello)? Also, the double-slash replacement (`${var//pattern/replacement}`) replaces all occurrences, but with an anchor there can only be one, so a single-slash replacement (just first occurrence) makes more sense. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: I thought I'd made it clear from the paths example. In this particular case I just want the replacement if it matches the front.
However the idea of passing it in through a command-line is that it would be up to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (emphasis added):

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`

- The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced with *string*. If *pattern* begins with ‘/’, all matches of *pattern* are replaced with *string*. Normally only the first match is replaced. **If *pattern* begins with ‘#’, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of *parameter***. If *pattern* begins with ‘%’, it must match at the end of the expanded value of *parameter*.

Note that it makes no sense to do a repeated search-and-replace on an anchored pattern since the anchored pattern can only match once. Consequently, `//` and `/#` are mutually incompatible. (Or, more accurately, the `#` in `${pattern//#.../...}` is not treated specially.)

As the manual says, `pattern` is a glob, not a regex, so it follows the same logic as [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching). Setting `extglob` will allow the use of "extended pattern matching characters", which make regex-like patterns possible.

The proof is in the pudding:

```
$ t1="hello there"
$ t2="there hello"
$ echo ${t1/#hello/goodbye}
goodbye there
$ echo ${t2/#hello/goodbye}
there hello
```

Comment: Ah! So they just invented some new anchor characters! If they work I can happily document them.
And the reason I didn't find that is I was searching for "//" as the command, not / followed by /
Thanks!.

Comment: @Gem: `#` and `%` are consistent with prefix and suffix deletion (See `${parameter#pattern}` and `${parameter%pattern}` replacements in the manual.) Unlike search-and-replace, those are Posix-compliant and therefore have been around for a long time.